# Label data-items with all combinations of two other JSON arrays in Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash, map-function

I'm using Lodash to convert one JSON structure into another. I need to form **all combinations** of two arrays and marry-up each combination with a data value taken from a third array.

How do I generate all combinations and extract the right data-item for each?

**Source** JSON structure:

```
{
    "regimes"      :   [ "AA", "BB" ],
    "axes"         :   [ "Horizontal", "Vertical" ],
    "data-items"   :   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
}
```

**Destination** JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "regime"      : "AA",
        "axis"        : "Horizontal",
        "data-item"   : 1
    },
    {
        "regime"      : "AA",
        "axis"        : "Vertical",
        "data-item"   : 2
    },
    {
        "regime"      : "BB",
        "axis"        : "Horizontal",
        "data-item"   : 3
    },
    {
        "regime"      : "BB",
        "axis"        : "Vertical",
        "data-item"   : 4
    }
]
```

Comment: do not you need,     `{"regime"      : "AA", "axis" : "Horizontal",  "data-item"   : 3}` and 4?

Comment: No. I'm **not** looking for all combinations of all three arrays. Rather, all combinations of the first two, and then associate each combination with a data-item taken **in order** from the third array. It's a bit counter intuitive! - I've double checked the JSON above and it is exactly as I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well:  (where x = source json)

Step 1. Get the DOT product of regimes and axes

```
    DOT = _(x.regimes)
        .map((r)  => {
            return x.axes.map((a)=> {
                return {
                    regime: r,
                    axis: a
                }
            })
        })
        .flatten()
```

Step 2. Get the data values

```
    data = _(x.data)
        .map((v)  => {
            return {data:v};
            }
        )
        .value()
```

Step 3. Merge the two

```
    // Merge the two collections

    result = _(DOT).merge(data)
```

Job done.

Answer (score 2):

I've came up with that hybrid and ugly solution. Maybe you can refactor it.

What I'm going to do is,

1) to take [cartesian product of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), `a["regimes"]` and `a["axes"]` which will give you,

```
[ "AA", "Horizontal" ] 
[ "AA", "Vertical" ] 
[ "BB", "Horizontal" ] 
[ "BB", "Vertical" ]
```

2) then, slice `a["data-items"]` to

```
first = [1,2]
last = [3,4]
```

3) and `zip`,

```
[[ "AA", "Horizontal" ],[ "AA", "Vertical" ]]
```

with `first = [1,2]`

and

```
[[ "BB", "Horizontal" ],[ "BB", "Vertical" ]]
```

with `last`. which will give us

```
[[ "AA", "Horizontal" ], 1]
[[ "AA", "Vertical" ],2]
[[ "BB", "Horizontal" ],3]
[[ "BB", "Vertical" ],4]
```

lastly we can easily call `map` on above array of arrays

```
above_multidimensional_array.map(e=>_.flatten(e))


_.zip(cartesianProductOf(a.regimes, a.axes)
  .slice(0,2), a["data-items"]
  .slice(0,2))
  .map(e=>_.flatten(e)
).concat(
  _.zip(cartesianProductOf(a.regimes, a.axes)
    .slice(2,4), a["data-items"]
    .slice(2,4))
    .map(e=>_.flatten(e))
).map(e=>({'regime': e[0], 'axis': e[1], 'data-item': e[2]}))
```

result:

```
[
    { regime: "AA", axis: "Horizontal", data-item: 1 } 
    { regime: "AA", axis: "Vertical", data-item: 2 } 
    { regime: "BB", axis: "Horizontal", data-item: 3 } 
    { regime: "BB", axis: "Vertical", data-item: 4 }
]
```

cartesian product implementations.

```
#https://gist.github.com/ijy/6094414#file-cartesian-product-js
function cartesianProductOf() {
    return _.reduce(arguments, function(a, b) {
        return _.flatten(_.map(a, function(x) {
            return _.map(b, function(y) {
                return x.concat([y]);
            });
        }), true);
    }, [ [] ]);
};

#https://gist.github.com/FestivalBobcats/1323387
function cartesianProductOf(){
    return _.reduce(arguments, function(mtrx, vals){
        return _.reduce(vals, function(array, val){
            return array.concat(
                _.map(mtrx, function(row){ return row.concat(val); })
            );
        }, []);
    }, [[]]);
}
```

[Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry @marmeladze I think you've used my required **output** as your **input**! My input is the FIRST block and my required output is the SECOND block. Maybe?

Comment: damn, how i did that? let me fix it -)))